# why is console.log not working with this code(i am not console.log (ging) infinitely)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

this is code for a simple cli(console line interface) todo app
but when ever this code is running
console.log does not work
I only tried in chrome

```
let todos = [];
let user_input = 0;
while (user_input !== "quit") {
    user_input = prompt("what would you like to do?");
    if (user_input === "new") {
        todos.push(prompt("what will be the todo"));
        console.log("bruh");
    } else if (user_input === "list") {
        for (let i = 0; i <= todos.length - 1; i++) {
            console.log(`${i + 1}: ${todos[i]}`);
        }
    } else if (user_input === "delete") {
        let index = parseInt(
            prompt("what is the index of item you want to delete")
        );
        todos.splice(index, 1);
        for (let i = 0; i <= todos.length - 1; i++) {
            console.log(`${i + 1}: ${todos[i]}`);
        }
    }
}
console.log("thanks for using me");
```

i am a beginner
sorry if it is dumb question
thanks in advance

Comment: Works for me in Firefox and Chrome. How exactly are you trying to use the code?

Comment: @pointy can you see
the console.log s ?

Comment: @Pointy every console.log in the while loop does not show up in console

Comment: Open your console and type `console.log("hello world")`. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the console tab in the developr tools and check that the Info is selected under the labels dropdown menu

[image]

Comment: what info?________

Comment: This should be a comment, as it does not provide an answer.

Comment: alright
can you give me a bigger screenshot
i cant see where it this option is

Comment: ow my log level is locked at default,
it is greyed out

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the "while" to "if" and it will work :)

Comment: This is incorrect; the code already works.

Comment: It is correct actually, the while loop won't let you reach the console.log so if you change that like i said it should work, and yes kinda late to reply lol, but still. Anyways, if anyone is willing to correct me then do so.